# I accidentally deleted my drive with DISKPART

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, diskpart

I was trying to fix my broken USB flash drive with DISKPART but I accidentally deleted my D drive (fortunately this is not my system drive).

I have a complete command history of what I've done but I was following online tutorial and I don't really understand what I did. Could you please help me undo anything that I have just done?

Thanks.

Note: first list disk command is before plugging the USB drive in, the second command is after plugging it in.

```
C:\Windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.10586

Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: PC-SAAM-AMD-FX

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online          223 GB      0 B

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online          223 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online         7712 MB      0 B

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online          223 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online         7712 MB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 3

The disk you specified is not valid.

There is no disk selected.

DISKPART> select disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> detail disk

Corsair Flash Voyager USB Device
Disk ID: 00000000
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

There are no volumes.

DISKPART> format recommended override

There is no volume selected.
Please select a volume and try again.

DISKPART> select volume

There is no volume selected.

DISKPART> select volume *

The arguments specified for this command are not valid.
For more information on the command type: HELP SELECT VOLUME

There is no volume selected.

DISKPART> select volume 1

Volume 1 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> format recommended override

Virtual Disk Service error:
Format is not allowed on the current boot, system, pagefile,
crashdump or hibernation volume.


DISKPART> FORMAT FS=NTFS LABEL="Windows7" QUICK COMPRESS

Virtual Disk Service error:
Format is not allowed on the current boot, system, pagefile,
crashdump or hibernation volume.


DISKPART> clean all

Virtual Disk Service error:
Clean is not allowed on the disk containing the current boot,
system, pagefile, crashdump or hibernation volume.


DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
* Partition 1    Primary            100 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            931 GB   101 MB

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
* Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online          223 GB      0 B
  Disk 2    Online         7712 MB      0 B

DISKPART> select disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> list partition

  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary           7710 MB  1024 KB

DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          931 GB  1024 KB
  Disk 1    Online          223 GB      0 B
* Disk 2    Online         7712 MB      0 B

DISKPART> detail disk

Corsair Flash Voyager USB Device
Disk ID: 00000000
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

There are no volumes.

DISKPART> clean all

DiskPart has encountered an error: The device is not ready.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART>
```

Comment: Uh ? As far as I can tell from your log you didn't actually damage/destroy anything. The CLEAN and FORMAT commands are the dangerous ones and they failed because you accidentally tried to run them on your boot-disk and/or C:-Drive.

Comment: @Tonny no, the clean all on disk 0 was unable to format C, but it did format D.

Comment: The only thing that commes to my mind is "select volume 1". I thought volumes are disk-only but now I've tried list volume and this is the output:

  Volume 0     E                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  ----------  
  Volume 1         Rezervováno  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  ----------  
  Volume 2         HDD 1000 GB  NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy
  ----------  
  Volume 3     C   SSD 240 GB   NTFS   Partition    223 GB  Healthy    Boot

Comment: Give [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) a try. It helped me recover deleted partition from accidental clean command in diskpart. Please read carefully the documentation though.

Comment: @guest I had some luck with that myself. The "recover deleted partition" function is pretty good.

Comment: @LPChip On second thought... You're right. I was assuming D: was the 2nd physical disk (disk1), but it seems it was a partition on disk0. In that case the CLEAN did delete it, but didn't actually overwrite any data.

Comment: @Tonny damn i was delusional. OP used `clean all`(secure erase), not `clean` alone. in this case...

Answer (score 3):

Using a Clean all on a disk, which formats that drive cannot be undone.

You can try recovering data with undelete tools, but this is unlikely going to bring back all data.

Best option here is to start restoring from backups. I assume you made backups, right?

Comment: Words of wisdom +1

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on LPChip's answer a little, here's what Microsoft say:

> clean [all]
>
> Removes any and all partition or volume formatting from the disk with focus. On master boot record (MBR) disks, only the MBR partitioning information and hidden sector information are overwritten. On GUID partition table (GPT) disks, the GPT partitioning information, including the Protective MBR, is overwritten; there is no hidden sector information.
>
> all
>
> Specifies that **each and every sector on the disk is zeroed, which *completely* deletes all data contained on the disk**.

As LPChip says, this is why everyone else† makes at least one backup of their important data every day.

<sub>† in reality, depressingly, many don't.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

So I've finally managed to revert it. I still don't know what happened exactly but it seems it only unassigned it's disk letter. In Disk Management I could still see my disk with the same amount of free space as before but without the letter, so I tried assigning D again and it works and all data seem unmodified.

Comment: :-) But do make some backups, just in case next time luck is not on your side.

Comment: I do backups regularly, but still... reinstalling all these 400 GB would take a lot of time at least :). But thanks a lot anyways! :)

Comment: What did you do specifically so other people might have sucess when they perform similar mistakes.

Comment: But I still wonder how could it be unassigned, there is nothing about it mentioned in the MS documentation :-/.

Comment: You're very lucky. Apparently that disk has a flag on it preventing it from being erased, but removing the driveletter is one of the steps that is being done. Hard lesson learned. Diskpart is a tool for the advanced user, and backups really is underestimated. ;)

Comment: Worked for me too!